# jquery .getJSON does not GET any data from CodeIgniter REST interface

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, rest, cross-domain

I'm using Phil Sturgeon's RESTful interface for CodeIgniter https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver and it appears to be working flawlessly.

On another server, I'm attempting to use jQuery to retrieve json data.

First I checked whether my js is messed up by using the flickr example in the jQuery documentation. That worked properly.

But when I substitute my url I don't appear to be getting any response.

```
         $.getJSON("http://myurl/apps/api/micronews/community/db/mydb/city/mycity/format/json/?jsoncallback=?",
          function(data) {
            console.log ('show me the data');
          });
```

I've also tried the equivalent ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://myurl/apps/api/micronews/community/db/mydb/city/mycity/format/json/",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(results){
  console.log(results);
  }
});
```

The access log on the external server shows the GET request to /apps/api/micronews/community/db/mydb/city/mycity/format/json/?callback=jQuery151029825189273083685_1310236439746&_=1310236439748 and a 200 response.

Hitting that page directly from the browser returns json encoded data.

Since the GET parameters are in the URL string, it shouldn't be an issue with CodeIgniter not configured properly. And the access log seems to suggest the GET request is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The solution work for me : 
In the `application/config/config.php` make these changes :

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE
```

Save my night !

Answer (score 1):

I guess that is why security filtering function worked.

> The security filtering function is called automatically when a new controller is invoked. It does the following:
>
> > If $config['allow_get_array'] is FALSE(default is TRUE), destroys the global GET array.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

So, try `$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE` or use Post method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
 $.getJSON("http://myurl/apps/api/micronews/community/db/mydb/city/mycity/format/json/?callback=?",
  function(data) {
    console.log ('ready to handle data');
  });
```

Comment: Appears to be failing silently. Maybe it's the json format. Here's what Flickr returns http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tag=cat&format=json&jsoncallback=? Sturgeon's interface returns [{"id":"2670","case_no":"012011071146","date":"20110509"]

Comment: Ah. You are actually running into a very interesting issue with CodeIgniter. By default CI destroys all GET parameters. You will need to re-enable the querystring in your CI configuration file (so `$this->get()` actually returns something) to get this to work.

Comment: Switching $config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING'; causes CodeIgniter to return an error. At best, the Firebug console shows a GET call in red with 200 OK, but nothing in the response. So I'm thinking the issue is in how CodeIgniter is handling the request.

Comment: You don't want `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING'` as that breaks the routing. Try `$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;` and `$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";`.

Comment: Setting PATH_INFO results in all calls to my CI taking me to the default main page.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `$.ajax()` and then you can pass in `crossDomain:true` instead of worrying about jsonp callback wrappers?

Comment: Seems I get a 200 response without any data.